# Dio v.4.x.x not catching SocketException (no internet connection)

Tags: flutter, socketexception, dio

Since I updated dio package v.4.0.0 the lib not handling no internet connection anymore.
The code here generate an exception inside dio_mixin.dart that not created a DioError exception inside my catch

My code:

```
try {

  var response = await dio.get('/children/${babyId.value}');

} on DioError catch (e) {
  print(e.response);
}
```

dio_mixin.dart code:

```
try {

  ...

} catch (e) {
      throw assureDioError(e, reqOpt);
}
```

Comment: Update: Resolved! I declare two different interceptor with two OnError method. After removing the first one, the second interceptor now works properly!